# Having trouble extracting textarea value with jquery

Tags: jquery, textarea

I am trying to extract the value from a textarea using jquery, but my debugger keeps saying that my variable `questVal` is undefined. Any ideas? Here's the code:

```
approveThis:function(event) {
var thisId = parseInt(event.target.id.replace('app', ''));
var questId = thisId;
var questSelect = '#questID' + questId;
var questVal = $(questSelect).val();
$.ajax({
    url:"includes/php/whatifApprove.php",
    data:{ approving:true, idNum:thisId, questionName:questVal }, 
    type:"POST",
    cache:false,
    success: function(data){
        console.log(questVal);
        $('#testMessages').html(data);
    }
});
return false;
```

Comment: Maybe an element with whatever value is in `questSelect` does not exist. There is not enough information for us to help you.

Comment: Maybe you can provide some HTML so we can see what you are trying to select

Comment: Just add alerts between each var showing the var, make sure they are as expected. If you can't figure it out, and it's still failing, replace "$(questSelect).val()" with a hardcoded value and see if that helps.

Comment: Mostlikely the questID is not derived as you expect. Why do you need `event.target.id`, if this is a handler then you can simply do `this.id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really haven't provided enough info, but in general that means when you do

`$(questSelect).val();`

it is returning undefined.  You are not selecting what you think you are selecting.

I would put a debugger at the first line in the `approveThis` function, and step thru line by line, making sure everything is what you expect it to be.

Comment: You were absolutely correct, sir. I was in the process of grabbing my php so that I could add it to the mix, and noticed a typo. I have been working this problem for like 3 hours! My God. Well, just you saying I'm not selecting what I think I'm selecting helped. Thanks.

Comment: sometimes all it takes is another pair of eyes.  If this answer helped, you should accept and possibly upvote it ;)